# Bind to class library settings

Tags: data-binding, wpf-controls, settings

I have an application that has a main window and the application has settings for width, height, left, and top so that it can remember it's size and position from session to session.  I have the XAML set up like this (similar for the other 3 properties):

```
Height="{Binding myHeight, Source={x:Static local:MySettings.Default}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

'local' is declared as an xmlns that is the root namespace for the program.  This works great.

However I have another application that is a class library but also contains a window.  I tried to set it up similarly, changing the 'local' definition to the root namespace of the class library, adding the settings with the same name to the settings for the class library, but in this one I just get the error 'local:MySettings was not found'.  What am I missing?  Is this not possible in a class library?

Comment: Are you talking about app.config settings or your custom settings.settings file?

Comment: It's the regular system built into visual studio, not my own system.  Go to the project properties, settings tab, and add all settings as integer type with user scope...

Comment: Then your class library is missing the app.config which is a file in your start up application.

Comment: It's built as a class library and since it's used by multiple solutions it doesn't have it's own application.  How would I fix this or do I need to just roll my own settings system?

Comment: Right mouse click on your library and add Settings.settings file.